# Stone Cech compactification of cartesian product

Tags: general-topology

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces. By the universal property of the Stone-Cech compactification, there is a canonical map
$$\Phi: \beta(X\times Y)\to \beta(X)\times \beta(Y).$$
It is not very hard to show that $\Phi$ is always a surjection.

My question: Is it known when $\Phi$ is injective?

I read somewhere that $\beta(X\times Y)\cong \beta(X)\times \beta(Y)$ (through an arbitrary homeomorphism?) if and only if $X,Y$ are pseudocompact. Maybe if these spaces are homeomorphic, the canonical map is automatically injective as well?

Comment: I haven’t thought too much about this particular case. But in general, it’s possible to have a functor $F : A \to B$ where for all $X, Y \in A$, there is some isomorphism $F(X \times Y) \cong F(X) \times F(Y)$, but with the canonical map $F(X \times Y) \to F(X) \times F(Y)$ never being an isomorphism (and with there actually existing objects in $A$ - obviously if $A$ is empty than the above is trivial). So I doubt you can read anything from the two spaces merely being homeomorphic.

Comment: See https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1959-090-03/S0002-9947-1959-0105667-4/ where the case of arbitrary products (not merely two factors) is done.

Comment: @GEdgar Are you sure that paper answers the question? In that paper they seem to talk about "arbitrary homeorphism" instead of "the canonical surjection is injective".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X, Y$ be completely regular topological spaces, consider $X \times Y$ as a subspace of $\beta X \times \beta Y$.
Hence $\beta X \times \beta Y$ is a compactification of $X \times Y$. As was mentioned by the OP, there exists a unique continuous extension $\Phi: \beta(X \times Y) \rightarrow \beta X \times \beta Y$ and $\Phi$ is surjective.

The following are equivalent:

1. $\Phi$ is injective.
2. $\Phi$ is a homeomorphism.
3. $\beta X \times \beta Y$ is "the" Stone-Cech compactification of $X \times Y$, i.e., there exists a homeomorphism $\Psi: \beta(X \times Y) \rightarrow \beta X \times \beta Y$, which extends the embedding.
4. $X$ is finite or $Y$ is finite or $X\times Y$ is pseudocompact.

*Proof*: 1 $\Leftrightarrow$ 2 and 2 $\Leftrightarrow$ 3 are obvious (for "$\Leftarrow$" note that $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ coincide on $X \times Y$, hence $\Phi = \Psi$). 
3 $\Leftrightarrow$ 4 is the hard part, and essentially due to Glicksberg, see his paper cited above by GEdgar, see also Engelking, General Topology, 3.12.21 (c). (For "$\Leftarrow$" note that, if $X$ is finite, $X = \bigoplus_{i=1}^n \{x_i \}$, then $\beta (X \times Y) \cong \beta(\bigoplus_{i=1}^n Y) \cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^n \beta Y \cong X \times \beta Y \cong \beta X \times \beta Y$.)

It should be noted that if $X \times Y$ is pseudocompact, $X,Y \neq \emptyset$, then, of course, $X$ and $Y$ are pseudocompact. But, in general, not vice versa, see Engelking, General Topology 3.10.19 and the comment after 3.10.25 for a counter-example. See also there 3.10.26 and 3.12.21 (b) for a discussion, when a product of two pesudocompact spaces is pseudocompact, or Glicksberg's paper §5.

Comment: Isn't it possible to have a homeomorphism $\beta(X\times Y)= \beta X \times \beta Y$ that does NOT extend the embedding? I think in Glicksberg's paper, such a homeomorphism need not be the identity map $X\times Y$ and then your answer might contain a flaw.

Comment: No, Glicksberg proves that every continous function $f: X \times Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has a continous extension to $\beta X \times \beta Y$. This characterizes $\beta X \times \beta Y$ as the Stone-Cech compactication via the embedding. Note, that this theorem, however, does *not* say that, if $\beta(X \times Y) \cong \beta X \times \beta Y$ (for a  homeomorphism not extending the embeddnig), then $X,Y$ are pseudocompact. But I'm not aware of any such example. Would be interesting to know, whether there is one at all.

Comment: To be more precise, $\beta X \times \beta Y$ is *equivalent* to the Stone-Cech compactication, but this is exactly 3. from my answer. See Engelking, General topology 3.6.3.

Comment: So to be completely precise: Glickberg proves the following: 

The following are equivalent for topological spaces: (1) $(\beta X \times \beta Y, \kappa: X\times Y \to \beta X\times \beta Y: (x,y)\mapsto (i_X(x),i_Y(y)))$ is a Stone-Cech compactification for $X\times Y$. (2) $X,Y$ are pseudocompact. Is this the correct formulation? I was under the impression that the homeomorphism $\beta(X\times Y)\cong \beta X \times \beta Y$ could be anything, but I didn't read the paper so it appears I was wrong.

Comment: No, not exactly: it doesn't suffice that $X, Y$ are pseudocompact, but their product must be pseudocompact.  On the oteher hand, (1) holds, if $X$ or $Y$ is finite.

Comment: So if I change $(2)$ by $X\times Y$ is pseudocompact, then the statement is true?

Comment: ... or $X$ is finite or $Y$ is finite, i.e., 4. from my answer above.

Comment: At some MSE post, I saw someone claim that $\beta(\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N})\ne \beta(\mathbb{N})\times \beta(\mathbb{N})$ (not homeomorphic) because $\mathbb{N}^2$ is not pseudocompact. So this argument needs modification, right? Because it could be true that there exists some other homeomorphism, so we have to exclude this case.

Comment: Yes, indeed, the above does not prove that $\beta(\mathbb{N}^2)$ and $(\beta\mathbb{N})^2$ are not homeomorphic.  However, they are definitely not homeomorphic, since the latter is not extremally disconnected, see Engelking, Gen. top 6.3.21.